# how to use angular to get data from a web endpoint?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, bower

I need to use angular to get data from a web endpoint and then it needs to show it to the user. The Environment should be configured using bower, using grunt as a task manager.

I already have bower, angular and boostrap installed, the layout of the page is done. The question is, how do I fetch the data from that endpoint to show it? (it's basically a list with id's and names)

Thank you

Comment: What does the endpoint return?

Comment: Make a `get` or `post` request to the endpoint api and do whatever you want to do with the data returned. What is the data fromat returned by the web endpoint.

Comment: @Zeokav it returns names and places with id's

Comment: JSON or XML? What format does it return the data in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use angular's $http service to retrieve data from endpoint. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

After that in callback function you will be able to use and save data from your endpoint into your controller.

And just render it as usual.

E.G:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'your url as a string'}).
    then(function(response) {
       // here your response goes. Use it.
       // in your case - your data will be in response.data
       console.log(response.data);
    }, function(response) {
       // here is the error if requset failed.
  });
```